# Read only lead status UI, update only from trigger

Tags: trigger, tasks, update, status

I want that the lead status change only when tasks are completed, i use triggers to do that, and it is OK;

What i want now, is to make the lead status read only on the page layout (it is not possible, because it is a standard field);

I have found a solution in the slackExchange using lead rule validation based on profile, this works when try tu update lead status from UI, but i have issue with triggers when updating lead status (Same profile);

There is a solution to do that (lead status updates only based on tasks triggers)?.

The Idea, it to have a "Task drivven process on the lead life cycle", this way, users are forced to do some tasks and follow the process;

Thank you;)

Comment: Try to create a check box hidden field, default as False value.  Then create a Validation Rule that avoid to change Status field if this check box is false.  Then, with your task trigger, edit the status and the checkbox field. After update the Lead records, uncheck and update again all leads affected.

Comment: Thank you Raspi;is this is the best solution?,  i can do that, but there is no better solution?

Comment: I usually use this method. At this moment don't know another way to do it. If you found it, tell us! jaja

Comment: Ok Raspi, thanks a lot for your help; this solution looks like a bypass, and not very clean for me; but i don't have another choice, i will do it, thanks again;)

Answer (score 1):

Hide the field from UI and create a formula field and display that field on UI. So no user will be able to Edit that.

Comment: You can't do that, the lead status field is a SPECIAL standard field, it must displayed on all the pagelayout, and you can't turn it "read only"

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that, the lead status field is a SPECIAL standard field, it must displayed on all the pagelayout, and you can't turn it "read only"